# where can I take an online Second course in Linear Algebra or second abstract algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra, stochastic-processes, online-resources

Hi i am looking for an online/independent study Second course in Linear Algebra or abstract algebra I and II? Can you point me in the right direction. I need college credit. I need help ASAP

Even a probability and stochastic processes class would work.

Comment: Is Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 free to download, or has that changed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about credits. But for an Abstract Algebra course you can chek out this source online for free:

[Abstract Algebra Harvard,Proffesor Benedict Gross](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra)

I also recommend the following book:

[Dummit Foote Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349)

Comment: I just need a course to graduate thats all so I don't think it would work but thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't understand, your plan isn't to take the class in your school, but rather take it online and validating it in you own school to let them graduate you?

Comment: Yeah, they dont offer it in the summer and I dont want to wait an extra semester to take 1 course.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the math department at your school and see if there is a professor there who is willing to take you as an independent study student for one course. You would be wise to lay out a pretty detailed plan/proposal prior to having this talk with the math department. In other words put together a proposal that includes everything you would normally find on the syllabus, including what text book, what chapters/ sections will be included in the course, what exercises you will do. Also include a detailed timeline / schedule for all of these things. You want to show that you are willing and able to follow through to the end and that you will not be much of an additional burden on the prof.  It would be well to model your proposal after the syllabus of from an actual class taught recently at your school. Good luck.

Comment: thanks I appreciate your detailed response. But being in such a big public university has taught me that my professors don't really care much about undergrads in general, i guess it might just be true for my university. I couldn't get them to do a 1-credit basic math course for me.

Answer (score 1):

www.mooc-list.com
“MOOC List” is a directory of Massive Open Online Courses (MOOCs) from different providers, including coursera and actual Universities, with free or paid certificates.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who might view this later, engineering outreach from university of Idaho seems to be a great resource for people looking to take some higher level (senior level in college) math courses for university credit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Khan Academy, Coursera or the MIT open courses.

Comment: He is looking for guidance. Don't finish your answer in just a sentence.